# Scheduler jobs in python

Tags: python, scheduler

I am trying use apscheduler to create a scheduler job.
This job need to be executed every day of the business days (Monday - Friday), between 14h - 20h, every hour. On Saturday this job need to be executed between 9h-13h every hour.

```
sched.add_job(job_function, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', ...)
```

How can I add the hours?

I can't use cron jobs.

Comment: Do you at least have some base code? You should demonstrate that you are trying to do something at least. There's a great module called `schedule` on PyPi that may help you.

Comment: Did you look at python schedule? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule

Comment: Post edited @Juan

Comment: Why can't you use cronjobs?

Comment: `at("16:00").do(job)`? You may just have to schedule them multiple times. I encourage you to read the official docs at https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/